# What is VLEE6M fare basis?

Tags: air-travel, fare-class, fare-basis

[image: Image from my ticket[1]]

I am flying to BOM (Bombay airport) from JED (Jeddah airport), my ticket is showing  VLEE6M fare basis. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fare basis is often a short hand code for the airline to pack certain rules and conditions into a very compact from for gate agents. It varies from airline to airline, so if you really want to do know the details, you need to call them up.

Some guesses:

- V: is the fare class: depends on the airlines. For United "V" would be a mid-range economy ticket (up-gradable)
- L: Low Season
- 6M: 6 months maximum stay.

When you booked you were given (and had to agree) to the exact fare rules. If you have a specific question about what you can or can't do with this ticket, I would look there first.

Answer (score 7):

It's the name of the fare you paid for travel.

Airlines have a long list of fares between every city pair. Each fare has a different price and comes with different conditions on its use.

Fare names often follow a pattern, the first letter (usually) describes the prime booking code for the fare, and the other letters have some meaning to the airline. The only VLEE6M fare I could find on this market was issued by Saudia (SV).

As @Hilmar stated, VLEE6M a six-month max stay economy restricted fare.

```
    V FARE BASIS     BK    FARE   TRAVEL-TICKET AP  MINMAX  RTG
  1   VLEE6M         V R   374.00     ----      -    3/ 6M EH01
PASSENGER TYPE-ADT                 AUTO PRICE-YES              
FROM-JED TO-BOM    CXR-SV    TVL-17JAN19  RULE-2000 IPRMEAS/33
FARE BASIS-VLEE6M            NORMAL FARE  DIS-N   VENDOR-ATP
FARE TYPE-ER      RT-ECONOMY RESTRICTED
SAR  1402.00   MPM  E05MAR18 D-INFINITY   FC-VLEE6M  FN-     
SYSTEM DATES - CREATED 04MAR18/0540  EXPIRES INFINITY

PUBLISHED RTG JED-BOM/SV      EF-05MAR18 DIS-INDEF
```